# Error: Numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used and Warning in GA

Tags: r, for-loop, permutation, genetic-algorithm

Here is my code and I am wondering why there are warning messages saying "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

```
    library(GA)
    library(readxl)
    > data1 <- 
    read_excel("C:/Users/nadiahalim/OneDrive/CS954/Scheduling/data1.xlsx")
    > View(data1)
    > data1
```

output for data1

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   Jobj    Pj    Dj    Wj
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    25    61     3
2     2     7   102     7
3     3    42    86     1
4     4    36    44     3
5     5    18   150     1
6     6    29   134     4
```

I want to reorder Jobj in such away that it will give the minimum completion time denoted by Cj. For-loops has been used in my code as follow:

```
Cj=0
i<- sample(data1$Jobj)
for(i in 1:i){
fitness <-function(j){
for(j in data1$Jobj){
Cj[j] <- data1$Pj[j]+sum(Cj[j-1])
}
print(Cj)
}
fitness()
```

Output for this code

```
numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
```

Then, I run for GA code:

```
GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = fitness, lower = 1, upper = 6, maxiter= 5, run = 20, optim = TRUE)
```

output for GA as follow and the warning stated that number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

```
    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthGA | iter = 3 | Mean = 25 | Best = 25
[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
```

then I run for

```
summary(GA)
```

output for summary GA

```
-- Genetic Algorithm ------------------- 

GA settings: 
Type                  =  permutation 
Population size       =  50 
Number of generations =  5 
Elitism               =  2 
Crossover probability =  0.8 
Mutation probability  =  0.1 

GA results: 
Iterations             = 5 
Fitness function value = 25 
Solutions = 
      x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
[1,]   4  1  6  3  5  2
[2,]   6  3  1  5  4  2
[3,]   6  2  3  4  1  5
[4,]   3  6  4  1  5  2
[5,]   4  6  2  1  5  3
[6,]   5  3  4  1  2  6
[7,]   2  1  6  3  5  4
[8,]   4  1  6  3  2  5
[9,]   3  6  1  2  5  4
[10,]  3  6  2  1  5  4
 ...                   
[35,]  4  5  6  2  1  3
[36,]  3  4  5  6  2  1
```

When I run for summary(GA), it seems work but I am curious about the warning messages.I would be grateful if someone could help me concerning this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RonakShah I have edit my post and make it more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do in `fitness` function can easily be achieved without `for` loop.

For example, the output that you get from `for` loop is

```
#[1] 25  32  74 110 128 157
```

and using `cumsum` we get the same thing.

```
cumsum(data1$Pj)
#[1]  25  32  74 110 128 157
```

The main issue however, is the `fitness` function should return only one value and not a vector of values like `cumsum`. So if you change the function to  something like this

```
fitness <- function(j) sum(j)
```

You can do :

```
fitness(data1$Pj)
#[1] 157

library(GA)
GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = fitness, lower = 1, upper = 6, 
         maxiter= 5, run = 20, optim = TRUE)
```

which returns no warning.

Comment: Actually I refer to *TSP problem using GA* (maximize total distance by obtaining the optimal route ). In my problem I want to minimize total completion time (by randomizing the job sequence). And the output should be in this form GA | iter = 503 | Mean = 0.0002776453 | Best = 0.0012239902
GA | iter = 504 | Mean = 0.0002369902 | Best = 0.0012239902
GA | iter = 505 | Mean = 0.0002356493 | Best = 0.0012239902
However, in my problem, I unable to randomize the job sequence and the output stated that _numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used_

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what GA function does, what I am trying to demonstrate here is the `fitness` function should return one value instead of vector of values to avoid the warning message.